# UK 26-30 Railcard online purchase form broken

Tags: uk, public-transport

the online form to buy a new 26-30 railcard in the UK seems to have a bug that bars me from buying it online (phone queues are impossible to get through, also can't be bought in a ticket office).

I need to validate my passport/ID card (presumably to verify my age) typing in a long identifying document code, including a **3 character country ID** ("e.g. GBR", the website suggests, unhelpfully, in my case). I have a German passport, so the country ID is "D", encoded in the document code as "D<<". But the form doesn't accept this. It says: "The country ID must comprise 3 characters". The FAQs even say to ensure copying the chevrons in case of codes shorter than the required characters. I think the form just doesn't recognise "<" as a regular character. Which is so poor!

Has anyone encountered this issue and got around it? As I say, this rail card cannot be bought at an office by its own website's admission, and the phone queues are impossible to get through. And I need it very soon to be eligible.

Many thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: Have you tried DEU instead of D?

Comment: You could also try the following train company websites which say they can sell the railcard online - they might work better than the railcard site. (1) https://railcards.eastmidlandsrailway.co.uk/  (2) https://railcards.avantiwestcoast.co.uk/ although Avanti say you can only buy online if you have a UK home address.

Comment: I'd also try DEU, in case the website developers didn't understand the travel document specs properly and just went with an ISO-3166-1 alpha-3 list because they were told that's what was in that bit of the MRZ (it is, but with extensions they might not have been aware of, such as D instead of DEU for Germany).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That would be DEU then according to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-3) wikipedia page.

Comment: Amazing. Wouldn't have guessed that in a million years! As it happens, I actually went to the trouble of holding for half an hour to buy it over the phone but have double-checked that DEU is accepted by the online form that blocked me!